# Logstash-Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm getting the below error while try to connect Logstash with Elasticsearch

```
        **log4j, [2015-01-17T17:19:00.559]  WARN: org.elasticsearch.discovery: [logstash-ip-10-181-166-160-1026-2020] waited for 30s and no initial state was set by the discovery**
```

logstash.conf

```
input {
      lumberjack {
        port => 5000
        type => "logs"
        ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
        ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"

    }

    }

    filter {
    grok { match => [ "message", "%{TIME:log_time}\|%{WORD:Message_type}\|%{GREEDYDATA:Component}\|%{NUMBER:line_number}\| %{GREEDYDATA:log_message}"]
             match => [ "path" , "%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA:loccode}/%{GREEDYDATA:_machine}\:%{DATE:logdate}.log"]
             break_on_match => false
    }

    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch{
            embedded => false
            host => "localhost"
            #host => "http://xxx.xxx.xxx:9200"
            port => "9300"
            cluster=>"Elasticsearch-Logstash"
            manage_template=> false
            index=>"doppleml-%{loccode}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            #template=>"/home/hduser/elasticsearch/logstash-1.4.2/doppleML_template.json"
            #template=>"/home/ubuntu/elkproject/logstash-1.4.2/doppleML_template.json"

         }

    }
```

**Elasticsearch.yml:**

```
  network.host: localhost
    cluster.name: Elasticsearch-Logstash
```

Do I need to include any changes with logstash or Elasticsearch configuration files?

Comment: Remove the `port` from your elasticsearch output. You are probably not using JRuby, so [it will default to http `protocol`](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/elasticsearch#protocol), which expects port 9200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not setting protocol it's likely defaulting to "http", but you're directly setting port to "9300" which isn't going to work. I'd either set protocol to "http" and set port to "9200" or set protocol to "node" or "transport" and port to "9300".

This page of the docs is helpful in setting/debugging output settings for logstash and elasticsearch:

http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/elasticsearch